# Xamarin Forms create a Clicked Event for CheckBox Control

Tags: checkbox, mvvm, xamarin.forms

so I am trying to use the CheckBox Control with MVVM logic. However the only event existing is CheckedChanged, which also triggers if I am navigating from the page for example.

I am searching for a Clicked event, like a button has.

Do I need to create a custom control with custom renderer, or is there a better solution?

Looking forward to replies.

[EDIT]

To provide more information about my issue, I will put code examples below.

My CheckBoxes are inside a ListView. Each CheckBox is defined like this in XAML:

```xml
<CheckBox 
     IsChecked="{Binding IsCompleted}">

     <CheckBox.Behaviors>
         <prism:EventToCommandBehavior
             EventName="CheckedChanged"
             Command="{Binding SubTaskStateChangedCommand}"/>
     </CheckBox.Behaviors>

</CheckBox>
```

The ItemSource of the ListView has a property IsCompleted and a DelegateCommand SubTaskStateChangedCommand. It is worth mentioning that i am using Prism.

In the constructor:

```cs
SubTaskStateChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnSubTaskStateChangedCommandExecuted);
```

Class SubTaskModel:

```cs
public DelegateCommand SubTaskStateChangedCommand { get; set; }

private void OnSubTaskStateChangedCommandExecuted()
{
    //Do something
}

private bool _isCompleted;

public bool IsCompleted
{
     get { return _isCompleted; }
     set { _isCompleted = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

So when I am navigating to another page in my ViewModel using the Prism NavigationService, the OnSubTaskStateChangedCommandExecuted Method gets triggered. However, I noticed that when this happens, the IsCompleted value DOES NOT change.

Comment: You could also use the IsChecked property and bind it to a VM property and do some action when this property in your VM changes.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that. However, if the CheckBox is checked and I navigate away, the property changes also. So the behavior of the IsChecked property is the same as the behavior of the CheckedChanged event.

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to do here! Could you help me with more details?

Comment: Sure. My main page works like a todo list, where you can complete tasks via a checkbox. When a task is completed, the new state (checked) should be saved in a database. You can also uncomplete a task by unchecking the checkbox. I would handle this via the CheckedChanged event, however if the current state is checked and I navigate away from the main page, the checkbox changes to unchecked and the CheckedChanged event triggers, eventually storing the state unchecked in my database.

Comment: the most strange thing here is why does your bool property changes to false whenever you navigate, because it shouldnt. can you show us some code examples on what you are doing on the CheckChanged

Comment: @RobertHaslinger  That should not be the case as stated Ricardo, navigation should not affect the value of your property.

Comment: Uhm, I thought so too. Thanks for your answers guys, I will try to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Share us some code about your question and CheckedChanged won't be trigger when you perform navigating action.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I edited my question to provide more information.

Comment: @Umar3x It is also worth mentioning that the property changes on the initual build up of the page.

Comment: This may caused by the prism library. You can add a bool property inside command method to distinguish whether the command is triggered by the navigating or other action.

Comment: I have thought about that already, but it seemed strange though. I mean it is a nice workaround, but I am trying to follow the SOLID principle and that really hurts. It gets really complicated since the navigation process takes place in the ViewModel and the SubTaskModel has no information about the VM at all.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Okay it might have been easier than I thought lol. FYI I added a bool property (isNotNavigation) that is set to true, whenever the IsCompleted property changes. After the CheckedChanged event it is set to false again. Seems to be working fine for now.

Comment: Glad to hear that workaround works!